# Combine while and for loop Python

Tags: python, while-loop

I'm looking for an efficient (maybe a native function that I don't know of) way of going through a string character by character as long as each consecutive character matches a criteria. As soon as it doesn't match the whole shebang can be terminated.

Here's the loop start:

```
while (char == '-' or char == '+') for char in string:
```

How to **efficiently** code this line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To loop through a sequence and terminate the loop once a condition isn't met, you can use `break`:

```py
for char in string:
  if char not in ('-', '+'):
    break

  do_something_with(char)
```

However, if you want to just collect those items matching the condition, you might be looking for [`itertools.takewhile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile):

```py
def find_sign_prefix(s):
  sign_prefix = list(itertools.takewhile(lambda char: char in ('-', '+'), s))
  return sign_prefix

print find_sign_prefix("--+-++---3.141592+-+")
# '--+-++---'
```

Or specifically for examining a prefix of a string, you can use a regular expression:

```py
def find_sign_prefix(s):
  # `[+-]*` means "a '+' or '-' character, zero or more times";
  # `re.search` only matches at the beginning of a string; 
  # group 0 is the matched substring
  return re.search([+-]*, s).group(0)
```

Comment: Thanks, I used `num += len(list(takewhile(lambda char: char in ('-', '+'), string)))`  How fast is takewhile? These strings can be long sometimes

Comment: If you're just counting them, there's no need to collect them into a list; instead you can do `num += sum(1 for _ in takewhile(lambda char: char in ('-', '+'), string))`.

Comment: Also if you're interested in efficiency there are multiple optimizations to this, e.g. if you prepare the set `{'+', '-'}` as a global constant the checks will be faster -- `sum(1 for _ in takewhile(SIGN_CHARS.__contains__))`. It doesn't matter how long the string is, only how long the prefix is, since `takewhile` stops as soon as the condition is broken. It's also possible that the regex approach will be faster still, again if you keep the regular expression as a global constant (`PREFIX_PATTERN = re.compile("[+-]*")`)

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over each character using a while loop, and break the loop if the condition you are looking for comes up

```
string = '....'

for i in range(len(string)-1):

    char_i = string[i]
    char_i_1 = string[i+1]
    if not (char_i == '-' and char_i_1 == '+'):
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for checking each character against a condition like this?

```
string = 'AB++-A+B-'
for char in string:
    if char == '+' or char == '-':
       # Do something
       print(char)
```